# How do you do HTML form testing without real user input simulation?

Tags: php, html, testing, browser, forms

this question is like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498996/how-do-i-fake-input-for-form-testing), except it's for PHP testing via browser. It's about testing your form input.

Right now, i have a form on a single page. It has 12 input boxes. Every time i test the form, i have write those 12 input boxes in my browser.

i know it's not a specific coding question. This question is more about how to do direct testing on your form

So, how to do recursive testing without consuming too much of your time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) is one of the most popular names in the field of web interface testing. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545079/choosing-an-automated-testing-tool).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use some big programs for test just one small form - you can use your own testing bike :)

```
    $args = array(/* Your _POST params */)
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Your local|remote url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    // Parse the response here
    // You may specify the loop with need args for your 12 checkboxes
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but i prefer pekka's suggestion. it's saving time  ;)